# More efficient function and for loop

Tags: r, performance, loops, statistics

I am trying to do a more efficient for loop. I know the existence of sapply, laaply, etc. but I don't know how to implement it in my code.

I have my function which I don't know if it is very efficient. I think I should improve this but I don't know how.

```
myfun <- function(a, b, c) {
  sum <- 0
  iter <- 0
  while (sum < c) {
    nr <- runif(1, a, b)
    sum <- sum + nr
    iter <- iter + 1
  }
  return(iter)
}
```

And here is the part which I would like to use an sapply or something similar.

```
a <- 0
b <- 1
c <- 2
x <- 0
for (i in 1:10^9) {
  x <- x + myfun(a, b, c)
}
```

Also, I need to make a sapply similar to this

```
sapply(1:10^9, functie(a ,b ,c))
```

But the sapply uses 1:10^9 as parameters, instead of a, b, c.

Comment: use `mapply`. Its multivariate version of `sapply`.

Comment: the ideea is that I need my function to be repeated 10^9 times, with the exact parameteres, not use vectors as parameteres. I hope I understood your answear, if not please give me an example

Comment: It seems that you want to have `x` equal to the sum of 10^9 calls to a function. And that the functions parameters do not vary. If this is the case, probably the solution is a vectorized version of the function.

Comment: If you want to repeat the function call with the same parameters 10^9 times, you could just do rep(myfun(a,b,c), 10^9). It would return a vector of the same value repeated 10^9 times. Or just myfun(a,b,c)*10^9 if the goal is to get the sum of the items

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't return the same value, everytime so I can't use rep which will print the same result 10^9 times. I've update the quiestion to include the body function, maybe you can get a better ideea.

Comment: Please see `Rcpp` version in my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70501243/6574038), it's very fast now.

Answer (score 2):

I think `replicate()` is what you may be looking for (I changed your `n` to something smaller).

```r
set.seed(1234)

n <- 10^2

y <- replicate(n, myfun(a,b,c))
sum(y)
# [1] 462
```

This matches your prior result.

```r
set.seed(1234)

a <-0
b <-1
c <-2
x <-0
for (i in 1:n){
  x <- x + myfun(a,b,c)
}

x
# [1] 462
```

Comment: This does it, but I need it for n = 10^9. I've tried replicate but it only gives optimal times only for numbers up to 10^5

Comment: The problem isn't replicate. The problem is your function `myfun()`. I think it is that which you need to try to optimize. Not the loop.

Comment: Also, replicate is as much fast as the for loop

Comment: do you have any suggestions, on how I should improve myfun?

Comment: You should open a new question

Comment: Yeah it really depends on your end goal. I can think of a few ways to approximate it. Like you can simulate 100,000 from your `myfun()` and then resample off of that distribution (maybe with `sample()` using weights). Should be faster than running that `while` loop a ton of times.

Comment: You can also loop through your `myfun()` in parallel which should yield a decent speed up in this case.

Answer (score 2):

### Recursion

Here is a recursive function `f()` that does the same job as `myfun()`.

```
f <- function(s=0) {
  if (s[length(s)] >= 2) {
    return(length(s) - 1L)
  } else {
    f(c(s, s[length(s)] + runif(1, 0L, 1L)))
  }
}

set.seed(42)

f()
# [1] 3

replicate(8, f())
# [1] 4 5 4 4 3 5 3 5

stopifnot(all.equal({set.seed(42);f()}, {set.seed(42);myfun(0, 1, 2)}))
```

However (and most likely for [that](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/56871) reason), it's just cooler, not faster.

### Rcpp

Learning from that, we may define the `while` loop in `Rcpp`.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
double myfun_cpp() {
  double s = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while (s < 2) {
    s = s + R::runif(0, 1);
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}
')
set.seed(42)

myfun_cpp()
# [1] 3

replicate(8, myfun_cpp())
# [1] 4 5 4 4 3 5 3 5

stopifnot(all.equal({set.seed(42);myfun_cpp()}, {set.seed(42);myfun(0, 1, 2)}))
```

### Now it's lightning fast:

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#         f 22.244076 22.639439 25.345203 22.927777 24.089196 35.82683   100   c
# myfun_cpp  3.204448  3.260542  3.843632  3.294618  3.347971 13.71213   100 a  
#     myfun 16.823981 17.125346 20.605663 17.516248 27.385791 28.63267   100  b 

set.seed(42); R <- 1e3
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f=replicate(R, f()), 
  myfun_cpp=replicate(R, myfun_cpp()), 
  myfun=replicate(R, myfun(0, 1, 2)), times=1e2L,
  control=list(warmup=1e1L))
```

Comment: Nice answer, upvoted! Perhaps you can try another this recursion `f <- function(x, y, z) ifelse(z <= 0, 0, f(x, y, z - runif(1, x, y)) + 1)`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Thanks! It gives me `f_Thom 34.537333 35.400257 37.718551 37.879699 39.250000 48.720606   100    d`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It seems different recursion implemetatations give really different performance :)

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding True. I'd love to see performance of recursions in `Rcpp` though, but I'm currently not that good in C++.

Comment: I added a `Rcpp` version and did a benchmark, hope it could help you a bit (I am not a cpp expert :P)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right, in my honest opinion.
Since you don't need to return a vectorized or multi-dimensional result but instead update an existing object at each iteration, the for loop you're suggesting is more than adequate.

If you want to take a look at some great discussion about this topic I suggest you to look at this link: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html

Edit: just to address the speed argument

```
start <- Sys.time()
purrr::map_dbl(1:1000, function(x) y + myfun(a, b, c)) %>% sum
end <- Sys.time()
end - start

# Time difference of 0.02593184 secs

start <- Sys.time()
y <- replicate(1000, myfun(a,b,c))
cumsum(y)[1000]
end <- Sys.time()
end - start

# Time difference of 0.01755929 secs

y <- 0
start <- Sys.time()
for(i in 1:1000){
  y<- y + myfun(a,b,c)
}
end <- Sys.time()
end - start

# Time difference of 0.01459098 secs
```

Comment: It seems correct, but it takes a lot of time.

Comment: Well, that's not a problem you'll solve using any of the other iteration functions. In my test using e.g. purrr::map(), like so:
```purrr::map_dbl(1:1000, function(x) y + myfun(a, b, c)) %>% sum```
was almost 2 times slower than with your for loop

Comment: Of course, I was overthinking and feel a bit like an idiot. `cumsum(y)[n]` obviously is the same as `sum(y)`! I have corrected

Comment: I didn't notice that too :D Doesn't change anything though in terms of speed

Answer (score 1):

I would probably solve this using `purrr::map()`. E.g. like this:

```r
c(1:1e9) %>% 
  purrr::map_dbl(
    ~ myfun(a, b, c)
  ) %>% 
  sum()
```

This first calls `myfun()` the same number of times as the length of `c(1:1e9)`, and stores the results in a numeric vector, then it uses `sum()` to add the results together.

My tests shows it's a bit faster than using `replicate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options

- A base R recursion method

```
f_TIC <- function(x, y, z) ifelse(z <= 0, 0, f_TIC(x, y, z - runif(1, x, y)) + 1)
```

- `Rcpp` implementation of `f_TIC`

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
int f_TIC_cpp(double x, double y, double z) {
  if (z <= 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return f_TIC_cpp(x, y, z- R::runif(0,1))+1;
  }
}
")
```

## Benchmarking

```
library(Rcpp)

f <- function(s = 0) {
  if (s[length(s)] >= 2) {
    return(length(s) - 1L)
  } else {
    f(c(s, s[length(s)] + runif(1, 0L, 1L)))
  }
}

f_TIC <- function(x, y, z) ifelse(z <= 0, 0, f_TIC(x, y, z - runif(1, x, y)) + 1)


cppFunction("
double myfun_cpp() {
  double s = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while (s < 2) {
    s = s + R::runif(0, 1);
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}
")

cppFunction("
int f_TIC_cpp(double x, double y, double z) {
  if (z <= 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return f_TIC_cpp(x, y, z- R::runif(0,1))+1;
  }
}
")

myfun <- function(a, b, c) {
  sum <- 0
  iter <- 0
  while (sum < c) {
    nr <- runif(1, a, b)
    sum <- sum + nr
    iter <- iter + 1
  }
  return(iter)
}

set.seed(42)
R <- 1e3
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f = replicate(R, f()),
  f_TIC = replicate(R, f_TIC(0, 1, 2)),
  f_TIC_cpp = replicate(R, f_TIC_cpp(0,1,2)),
  myfun_cpp = replicate(R, myfun_cpp()),
  myfun = replicate(R, myfun(0, 1, 2)), 
  times = 1e2L,
  control = list(warmup = 1e1L)
)
```

and we will see

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
         f 11.9342 12.50330 14.161982 13.02100 14.96575 22.7116   100
     f_TIC 20.1925 21.69420 23.678240 22.28255 24.86350 34.1577   100
 f_TIC_cpp  2.0293  2.10080  2.639625  2.17505  2.36190  7.9715   100
 myfun_cpp  1.7351  1.79415  2.094577  1.83810  2.00495  6.7481   100
     myfun  9.1408  9.45240 11.783504 10.32355 14.68815 19.5400   100
```

Comment: Nicely done+1! The ratio for c++recursion/recursion appears to be smaller than c++while/while, very interesting!

Comment: @jay.sf Yes, interesting finding!